# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 28952 when adding drawable to the custom marker icon in mapbox android

Tags: android, mapbox, marker

I am trying to use custom marker icon in the mapbox.
So my code here follows

```
 private Marker createMarker(MapView mapView, double latitude, double longitude, String s) {

        if (mapView != null) {
            IconFactory mIconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(getActivity());
            Drawable mIconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(CPAApp.get(), R.drawable.car_disable_parking_grey);
            Icon icon = mIconFactory.fromDrawable(mIconDrawable);

            return this.mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .snippet(s)
                            .icon(icon)
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            );

        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Adding custom icon is successful when i have icon in **drawable folder only**.

> When I have same icon in **drawble-hdpi** , **drawable-xhdpi** and **drawable-xxhdpi**, I am getting this error **Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 28952** and app gets crashed.

Can anybody help me out from this problem. Thanks in Advance.